# strange characters in trusty

Tags: 14.04, ati, radeon, gpu-driver

From time to time I'm getting strange characters displayed in different programms: thunderbird, firefox mostly, but also nautilus.
Often it is only one character which is crumbled, but all over the active window.
I asked this question some days ago in the [ubuntu forums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2249718), but got no answers there.
I thought it's an hardware issue. I used the newest Catalyst-Driver for some time, the strange characters did not appear then, but the system froze from time to time. So this is not a solution. 
I switched back to the radeon driver, which is stable.

How can I get rid of the strange characters.

```
System:
Host: ttpit-black Kernel: 3.13.0-37-generic x86_64 (64 bit, gcc: 4.8.2) 
Desktop: Gnome Distro: Ubuntu 14.04 trusty
Machine:   Mobo: Intel model: DH67BL version: AAG10189-205
Bios: Intel version: BLH6710H.86A.0160.2012.1204.1156 date: 12/04/2012
CPU:       Quad core Intel Core i5-2500 CPU (-MCP-) cache: 6144 KB flags: (lm nx sse sse2 sse3 sse4_1 sse4_2 ssse3 vmx) bmips: 26339.8
Graphics:  Card: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD/ATI] Bonaire XT [Radeon HD 7790/8770 / R9 260 OEM] bus-ID: 01:00.0 
X.Org: 1.15.1 drivers: ati,radeon (unloaded: fbdev,vesa) Resolution: 920x1200@60.0hz 
GLX Renderer: Gallium 0.4 on AMD BONAIRE GLX Version: 3.0 Mesa 10.1.3 Direct Rendering: Yes
```

here are some pictures
http://www.bienenhof-kriele.de/crumbled_4.jpg
If you change the numbers in the link from 2 to 5, you can see the other images

... I have still this issue, nobody with a solution out there?

Comment: Welcome to askubuntu.com ! Could you please post the pictures from the forum here as well ? Some of us who dont have Ubuntu One account or not registered in the forum wont be able to view the pictures

Comment: I'm having the same issue I think... when hovering over the characters with the mouse, they disappear, but they do show up on a screenshot... really strange this, did you ever find a fix for it?

Comment: no - no fix for me yet. And you are right, they disappear by scrolling or mouse-up. And with the catalyst it is o.k., but for stability the radeon would be the better solution.